# Oracle query with just sub selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to return 1 row with three columns

```
(SELECT count(1) from tests) TestCount, 
(select count(1) from customers) CustomerCount, 
(select count(1) from patients) PatientCount
```

Comment: Just to make sure the urban legends aren't kept alive: `count(1)` is **not** faster than `count(*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  (SELECT count(1) from tests) TestCount, 
  (select count(1) from customers) CustomerCount, 
  (select count(1) from patients) PatientCount
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TestCount.TestCount,
        CustomerCount.CustomerCount,
        PatientCount.PatientCount
FROM    (SELECT count(1) TestCount from tests) TestCount
        CROSS JOIN
        (select count(1) CustomerCount from customers) CustomerCount
        CROSS JOIN
        (select count(1) PatientCount from patients) PatientCount
```